# How can I run a vlookup function in SQL within the same table?

Tags: sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and struggling to find a good way to run the following query.

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
NAME       JOB GRADE     MANAGER NAME
X          7             O
Y          6             X
Z          5             X
A          4             Z
B          3             Z
C          2             Z
```

In this table, it shows that Y and Z report into X, and A, B and C report into Z.

I want to create a computed column showing the grade each person's most senior direct report or "n/a" if they don't manage anyone. So that would look something like this:

```
NAME       JOB GRADE     MANAGER NAME     GRADE OF MOST SENIOR REPORT
X          7             O                6
Y          6             X                N/A
Z          5             X                4
A          4             Z                N/A
B          3             Z                N/A
C          2             Z                N/A
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Post formatted text. You can rollback your edit to the previous (much better) version.

Comment: Computed column? Are you using SQL Server? (Tag dbms used, and you'll get better answers, faster.)

Comment: Is this a query you need to run, or an actual storage you need to maintain (because the data volume is hundreds of millions of rows)? Have you researched VIEWS, INDEXED VIEWS, and the EFT OUTER JOIN operation (specifically a self left outer join back to the same table?

Comment: Does the `O` mean `NULL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select name, job_grade, manager_name, 
       (select max(job_grade) from grades g2 
        where g2.manager_name = g1.name) as grade_of_most_recent_senior
from grades g1
order by name;
```

The above is ANSI SQL and should work on any DBMS.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e0806/1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT g.*,isnull(convert(nvarchar, (SELECT max(g2.GRADE) 
FROM dbo.Grade g2 WHERE 
g2.manager  =g.NAME  AND g2.NAME!=g.NAME    )),'N/A') as most_graded
FROM dbo.Grade g
```

The [max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187751.aspx) will find out the topmost graded

**Input**

---

```
X   7   O
y   6   X
Z   5   X
A   6   Z
C   2   Z
```

**Output**

---

```
X   7   O   6
y   6   X   N/A
Z   5   X   6
A   6   Z   N/A
C   2   Z   N/A
```